# Selecting variable and storing into multi-dimentional array

Tags: php, arrays

I understand how multi-dimentional array works but iam new to it.

eg.

```
$arrayAns = array( subject => "he"),
            array( subject => "I"),
            array( subject => "they");
```

What I am trying to do is, get a variable from database and store it in the array.

```
$query = "SELECT subject FROM #__wordBank ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
        $db->setQuery($query);
        $rows=$db->loadObjectList();

$arrayAns = array( subject => "$rows")
```

Is that the way to do it?

Comment: You have a syntax error in the code you posted... You missed an `a` in the last element of `$arrayAns`.

Comment: Also your syntax for a multi-dimentional array is slightly flawed... I'm going to assume this was a mistake when posting the question and that your actual code doesn't look exactly like that...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
If the results from database are stored in `rows`:

```
$newArray = array();
foreach($rows as $key=>$value) {
 $newArray[] = $value;
}
```

Here, all the variables in `$value` would be stored into the `newArray`.

Also, see [array_push](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)

Comment: The OP has specified a `LIMIT 1` on his query and is also only selecting one field.  I do not believe that `$rows` would have more then one element itself... `foreach` is not needed here...

Answer (score 0):

Change you syntax to look like this (you also had [some syntax errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11501889/selecting-variable-and-storing-into-multi-dimentional-array#comment15195551_11501889)) -

```
// original multidimensional array
$arrayAns = array(
  array( "subject" => "he"),
  array( "subject" => "I"),
  array( "subject" => "they")
);

// execute query
$query = "SELECT subject FROM #__wordBank ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
$db->setQuery($query);
$rows=$db->loadObjectList();
```

Now what we want to do is add another element to your original array.  You can use the short hand `[]` syntax to push another element on to the top of the array.

```
$arrayAns[] = array('subject'=> $rows['subject']);
```

That line is functionally identical to this one -

```
array_push($arrayAns, array('subject'=> $rows['subject']));
```

Comment: Hi guys thx for helping me out, just to check my understanding.If i need to select more than one i could do this:

    $query = "SELECT subject FROM #__wordBank ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
            $db->setQuery($query);
            $rows1=$db->loadObjectList();
    
    $query = "SELECT verb FROM #__wordBank ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
            $db->setQuery($query);
            $rows2=$db->loadObjectList();
    
    $arrayAns[] = array('subject'=> $rows1['subject']);
    $arrayAns[] = array('verb'=> $rows2['verb']);

true?

Comment: Yes - essentially that *could* work.  Although I'm pretty sure you could optimize that to not have to make more than one query.  Without having more details it would be hard to know for sure...

Answer (score 0):

Almost! But not quite

Here is how I would go about this:

```
$arrayAns = array(
    array('subject' => "he"),
    array('subject' => "I"),
    array('subject' => "they")
);

$query = "SELECT subject FROM #__wordBank ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
$db->setQuery($query);
$rows=$db->loadObjectList();

$arrayAns[] = array('subject' => $rows);
```

Comment: Depending on what `loadObjectList()` returns... `$rows` might just be an associative array within itself - pushing it like that onto the array would not achieve the same format that the OP specified...

Comment: I think you'll find it's exactly the same as the origin format

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what DB API are you using you may have an option to retrieve the data as a multidimensional array automatically. Check if $rows->toArray() is possible or something like that.

Otherwise not the most optimal, but easy and clean way is to foreach through your $rows list and build the array you want.

Btw, the array you have defined on top is defined like this in PHP:

```
$myArray = array(
    array(
        'subject' => 'he'
    ),
    array(
        'subject' => 'I'
    ),
    array(
        'subject' => 'they'
    )   
);
```